# Streaming a http video on an android application

Tags: android, remote-access, jsch, portforwarding

I'm trying to make an android app on the android studio that sshs into a remote sever and runs a command. It also has to forward the port 8080 from the remote sever that is setup an HTTP stream over vlc. This is then to be used in a videoview widget that displays the video in the application. This app runs without errors in the logcat and runs the ssh command successfully but the video view just shows a black box--I suspect that there's something wrong with my code. Any help would be grand!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            try {
                executeRemoteCommand0("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", 22, videoView);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute(1);

    try {
        sleep(5);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


 videoView.setVideoPath(String.format("http://localhost:%d/video.mp4", 5000));

    videoView.start();

}


public String executeRemoteCommand0(String username, String password, String hostname, int port, VideoView videoView) throws Exception {

    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, port);
    session.setPassword(password);

    // Avoid asking for key confirmation
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(prop);

    int camport = session.setPortForwardingL(5000, hostname,8080);
    session.connect();


    // SSH Channel
    ChannelExec channelssh = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    channelssh.setOutputStream(baos);

    // Execute command

    channelssh.setCommand("command");
    channelssh.setPty(true);
    channelssh.connect();

    return baos.toString();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in this line:
`videoView.setVideoPath(String.format("http://localhost:%d/video.mp4", 5000));`

You are trying to reference `localhost` from the mobile device itself. You should replace it with the real IP address or domain name of the server you are using to stream the video.

Also, it's a bad practice to sleep your main thread on Android. Try to avoid this.

Comment: I thought after forwarding the port 8080 of the remote sever to 5000 of the local server you can access it locally? Also, I tried to put the video view into the asynchronous task but it throws up a 'need to declare looper.prepare() and when I do all the variables are not resolved within the function anymore from the external libraries. I know its super clunky :/

Comment: Referencing `localhost` means that you have an instance of the server deployed on the mobile device (which is obviously not the case). You need to set the video player path on the main thread. You can implement the `onPostExecute()` method of your `AsyncTask`. It will be called on the main thread after the background is done.

Comment: Is there a need to forward the port originally then? Or does it function as a URL ? Thanks for the tip about the onPostExecute() :)

Comment: I don't think you need to forward the port at all.